# Implementing Blockwise Low-Pass IIR Filter in Python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

This question is similar to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60694 but I'm reframing it as a Python implementation question to be more aligned with the solution I'm seeking.

I want to implement a Low-Pass IIR Filter that operates on nearly-realtime chunks of audio (441 data points per chunk X 100 Hz = 44.1 kHz).  There are a lot of buzzing artifacts.  I expect it has something to do with how I'm using the scipy.signal methods and setting up the initial conditions.

First, I tried to understand the Theory behind what I'm doing per the conversation on the DSP forum, but I've long forgotten my DSP college course, so it doesn't make much sense to me.  Next, I tried many, many combinations of code, and the only one that works (no artifacts) is a very specific combination of functions and parameters.

```py
Bparam, Aparam = signal.iirfilter(2, 0.020, btype = 'lowpass', analog =
       False, ftype = 'butter')       # 2nd order Butterworth coefficients

Z = signal.lfilter_zi(Bparam, Aparam) # Part of the init conditions calc

IC = Z * (prevSignal[::-1])[0:2]      # Reverse prevSignal and then grab
                                      #   only the last two elements

filteredSignal, _ = signal.lfilter(Bparam, Aparam, inputSignal, zi = IC)
                                      # Result is continuous and clear

prevSignal = filteredSignal           # Save for the next pass
```

I test my filter two ways.  The first is with inputSignal being an np.sin wave, and the expected output is an undistorted sine wave.  The second is to add a few odd harmonics (constructing a band-limited square wave) and verify the result bears smaller ampllitudes of those harmonics, as a low-pass filter would.

The above code meets expectations when the order is second-order, but with higher orders the distortion is present.  I tried, for example, setting the IC range at [0:4] and it doesn't seem to work the same way.

Comment: Take a look at the section "Filtering a long signal in batches" starting on page 6 of my notes on using [linear filters in SciPy](https://warrenweckesser.github.io/papers/weckesser-scipy-linear-filters.pdf).

Comment: @Wareen Weckesser can you please help me out with a problem implementing 2 lowpass filters in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper by @Warren (which IMHO is excellent), the *Filtering a long signal in batches* section helped to answer my question.  Along with the example code provided in that section, I formed the `sos` array by:

```py
Bparam, Aparam = signal.iirfilter(2, 0.02,
                   btype = 'lowpass', analog = False, ftype = 'butter')
Z, P, K = signal.tf2zpk(Bparam, Aparam)
sos = signal.zpk2sos(Z, P, K)
```

I've also tried this on high-pass filters, too, up to 8th order, no problems!